# Как получать координаты определенного угла при вращении элемента?

Tags: javascript, rotation, координаты

Я хочу получать координаты левого нижнего угла(изначального).

```
deg = 0;
setInterval(()=>{
    deg+=1;
    document.getElementById("div1").style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;
},20);
```

Пробовал находить их через `getBoundingClientRect()`, но он, как я понял, находит кратчайшее растояние, а мне нужно расстояние от левой нижней точки (изначальной).

P.S.

```
#div1{
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: А как проиcходит вращение  -  вокруг центра прямоугольника? И координаты относительно чего?

Comment: Относительно родительского элемента или окна, без разницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В начальный момент координаты угла относительно центра были

```
x0 = -width / 2
y0 = height / 2  //знак зависит от направления осей
```

После вращения  вокруг центра (angle в радианах)

```
x = x0 * Cos(angle) - y0 * Sin(angle) = 
   -width / 2 * Cos(angle) - height / 2 * Sin(angle)
y = x0 * Sin(angle) + y0 * Cos(angle) = 
    -width / 2 * Sin(angle) + height / 2 * Cos(angle)
```